# Merge two parquet files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, merge, hdfs, parquet

I have some files in `HDFS` in `parquet` format. I would like to merge these files into one single large file.

How can I do that?

I have done some thing like below but for text files.

```
hadoop fs -cat /input_hdfs_dir/* | hadoop fs -put - /output_hdfs_file
```

But unable to achieve the desired result in `parquet` format.

How can I achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to merge `parquet` files with hdfs commands.

There is a [parquet-tools library](https://github.com/nielsbasjes/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools) that can help you achieve the `merging` of `parquet` files. The command should be

```
java jar ./parquet-tools-<VERSION>.jar <command> <input-directory> <output-file>
```

Comment: I think `parquet-tools` comes pre-installed with Cloudera these days.

Answer (score 0):

The same tool can be used to merge multiple files inside the Hadoop just use  $hadoop jar instead of $java -jar before ./parquet-tools