# Parquet write OutOfMemoryException on spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have about 8m rows of data with about 500 columns.
When I try to write it with spark as a single file `coalesce(1)` it fails with an `OutOfMemoryException`.

I know this is a lot of data on one executor, but as far as I understand the write process of parquet, it only holds the data for one row group in memory, before flushing it to disk and then continues with the next one.

My executor has 16gb of memory and it cannot be increased any further. The data contains a lot of strings.

So what I am interested in is, some settings where I can tweak the process of writing big parquet files for wide tables.

I know i can enable/disable dictionary, increase/decrease block- and pagesize.

But what would be a good configuration for my needs?

Comment: But why do you need single file? Generally it would be bad practice, since you just kill all parallelism with that.

Comment: That is ok, I can live with longer runtime on write. I don't want to many read requests when I query the table. Not repartitioning would result in a lot of small files, which is also bad practice. Since parquet is splittable, i have parallelism on read

Comment: Have you also considered writing without `coaelsce` and then [merging parquet files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44400331/merge-two-parquet-files-in-hdfs)?

Comment: Yes, we had that before, but we wanted to do it in a single step.

Comment: So my question is really on the parquet configuration

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Parquet is really contributes to failure here and tweaking its configuration probably won't help.

`coalesce(1)` is a drastic operation that affect all upstream code. As a result, all processing is done on a single node, and according to your own words, your resources are already very limited.

You didn't provide any information about the rest of the pipeline, but if you want to stay with Spark, your best hope is replacing `coalesce` with `repartition`. If OOM occurs in one of the preceding operations it might help.

Comment: The rest of the pipeline works fine. The final two stages are repartition / coalesce (i don't know which one is used if i use distribute by in spark-sql) and write as parquet. The failures occur in the final stage, when the parquet files are written. I sure there is a configuration that would let me write a big file with 500 columns, but i don't know where to tweak

Comment: `DISTRIBUTE BY` is a completely different beast, not related to `coalesce` or `repartition`, and you didn't mention it in your question. Also, failures happen when there is an action. No write (or equivalent) = no action, so if something doesn't fail, it does it mean it works.